# Your Ruby version is 2.1.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv, gemfile

In my Gemfile I specified ruby version 2.0.0:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
```

But my console tells me I have 2.1.0dev:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0dev (2013-09-16 trunk 42951) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
```

I am using rbenv and it tells my I don't have 2.1.0 installed,

```
$ rbenv versions
system
* 2.0.0-dev
```

Bundle update or bundle install says:

```
"Your Ruby version is 2.1.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0"
```

but using 'rbenv local 2.0.0-dev' leaves me with ruby 2.1.0dev again. Furthermore:

```
$ rbenv global
2.0.0-dev

$ cat ~/.bash_profile:
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

As far as I know, 2.1.0dev doesn't even exist yet.

How can i get ruby 2.0.0 selected?

Comment: Seems like rbenv is busted.  Reinstall?

Comment: $ rm -rf ~/.rbenv
$ brew uninstall rbenv
$ $ brew update
$ brew install rbenv
$ brew install ruby-build
$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
$ rbenv install 2.0.0-dev
$ rbenv rehash

Gives me the same:
    $ ruby -v
    ruby 2.1.0dev (2013-09-16 trunk 42951) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]

Comment: 2.0.0-p247 cannot be found either

Comment: What does `which ruby` say?  Where is this magic ruby coming from?

Comment: I wish I could tell you. 
which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to update your version of `ruby-build` to make sure you have [the update](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/commit/81bbb68de6f9cbe348bd0867b45bcd86d83cd179) where `ruby-2.0.0-dev` switched to follow the `ruby_2_0_0` branch.

Try running `ruby-build --version` and make sure it's one of these (or later):

- v20130907
- v20130901
- v20130806
- v20130628
- v20130518
- v20130514
- v20130501
- v20130408
- v20130227
- v20130226
- v20130225

If not, run `brew upgrade ruby-build`.

Comment: I did had to reinstall rbenv and rails4 again though.

Comment: It's pretty typical to have to reinstall gems when changing to a new Ruby version.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Gemfile and change the description there
I just got the same problem and couldn't find a "working" solution. So I made my own.

source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0' #Change this one to this '2.1.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.3'