# Mavericks, RBENV, Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, bundler, osx-mavericks

I've read and tried the suggestions in [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0), [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837415/your-ruby-version-is-2-1-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-0-0), [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199970/bundlerrubyversionmismatch-your-ruby-version-is-1-9-3-but-your-gemfile-speci), [like mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342044/in-ruby-your-ruby-version-is-1-9-3-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-0-0) (all with accepted answers) as well as a few more hours of Google searching, but nothing worked. That leads me to think my issue is something corrupt with a piece of Ruby/RBENV ecosystem on my computer or maybe a dreaded PATH issue. I always have to run `sudo` to install any gems, which I've never had to do before, so that's puzzling too.

Here are some outputs of files & commands I think are relevant. If you need more information, please let me know:

.zshrc

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin" if which rbenv > /dev/null;
then eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"; fi
```

ruby -v

```
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

rbenv local

```
2.1.1
```

Gemfile (I've also blown out my gemfile.lock several times too)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.1'

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
... [omitted for brevity]
```

.ruby-version

```
2.1.1
```

echo $PATH

```
/[user path]/.rbenv/shims:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I'd be grateful if anyone has any ideas about what I should try next, short of reformatting my computer.

**EDIT 1:** Tried option B installing both of them from their git repos below as per Ben Kreeger. `type rbenv` correctly returned rbenv is a shell function and the original message kept appearing. I reinstalled Mavericks and my setup still isn't working.

**EDIT 2:** Any time I try to install a gem, I get a `Gem::FilePermissionError` saying I don't have access to the Ruby 2.0.0 folder (installed as system). Going to fiddle with RBENV some more...

**EDIT 3:** More debugging (everything below)

Kept erroring when installing Ruby versions with RBENV and found some people mentioning `readline` issues.

Tried the following steps to fix readline: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/550#issuecomment-40681557, and got an error that my Xcode command line tool install was bad.

Ran `xcode-select --install` to reinstall them.

Tried `rbenv install 2.1.1` again, and got `The Ruby openssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?`

As per https://coderwall.com/p/n9bnug, I linked my OpenSSL extension with `https://coderwall.com/p/n9bnug`

Reset versions of Ruby: `rbenv local 2.1.1` `rbenv global 2.1.1` and `rbenv rehash`

Everything seems to indicate bundler is trying to use my `system` Ruby install (2.0.0-p247) instead of what RBENV is specifying. Baffled where the missing link is.

Comment: How did you install `rbenv` in the first place — by installing everything to `~/.rbenv` through git, or by a `brew install rbenv`?

Comment: Homebrew like always. I may have `sudo`ed it because of some other issue though. Can't remember. Mavericks caused a bunch of issues I'd never seen.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

WOW, JUST WOW.

All I had to do was `gem install bundler` and then `rbenv rehash`. Everything worked.

The original error message pointed me to a problem with RBENV or my Ruby version when in reality it was just falling back on an old version of bundler.

Why wouldn't I have received the more standard `this needs bundler version [xxxx]...` error instead of telling me my Ruby version is specified incorrectly?

Comment: I think your problem was that you had originally installed Bundler under the system Ruby, hardcoded to use that version, rather than installing Bundler into the version of Ruby managed by rbenv.

Comment: My apologies. SO wouldn't let me accept my answer immediately. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

If you're having to use `sudo` to install gems, then something's likely wrong with your rbenv installation. I'm of the opinion that if you're on OS X and you have to run `sudo` to install gems or packages, you're doing it wrong (especially if you've got `homebrew` installed)! You've got two options —

**Option A**: Alter your `.zshrc` to be a little more friendly with your `$PATH` and your rbenv settings. Note here that `/usr/local/bin` is just being prepended to `$PATH`, which itself is going to set to a proper default by your system (Mavericks). Make those two lines you posted look like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Then ensure that you close any and all shells and open new ones to load the new settings. Then when you run `echo $PATH` it should look similar to...

```
[home path]/.rbenv/shims:[home path]/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

**Option B**: Since I'm more familiar with installing rbenv via git, you may try nuking your homebrew-installed rbenv installation by `brew remove rbenv`, and follow [the directions specified on rbenv's github page](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#basic-github-checkout) (and don't forget to [install ruby-build as well](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build#installing-as-an-rbenv-plugin-recommended)). This includes removing any rbenv-specific lines in your `.zshrc` and setting them to [what rbenv recommends](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#basic-github-checkout).

You can always check the sanity of your rbenv installation by running `type rbenv` at a command prompt. If all is well, you should at least be getting back `"rbenv is a function"`.

Comment: Followed everything perfectly and still getting the message. Time to reformat?

Comment: Which option did you follow? Did you try `type rbenv`?

Comment: Tried option B installing both of them from their git repos. `type rbenv` correctly returned `rbenv is a shell function` and the original message kept appearing. I reinstalled Mavericks and my setup still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running **first**

```
rbenv shell --unset
```

Then I was able to set the version via

```
rbenv local <ruby_version>
```