# Can't run the correct Ruby version with rbenv

Tags: ruby, bundle, rbenv

After installing `rbenv`, I wanted to switch to the correct Ruby version to work on a project, but there seems to be an issue recognizing it.

```
$ cd project/
$ bundle install
$ Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1
$ rbenv local
$ rbenv: no local version configured for this directory
$ rbenv global
$ 2.1.1
$ ruby --version
$ ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: does the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061598/mavericks-rbenv-your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-1) help at all?  did you set your path right?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with my `$PATH` variable.

This worked for me (in `.bash_profile`):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```