# Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5

Tags: javascript, ios, ruby, react-native, gemfile

I have installed node@16(`v16.18.0`) in macOS and npm version: `8.19.2`.

- ***Operating System macOS(Monterey) version:*** `12.6`
- ***Xcode Verion:*** `14.0.1`

Followed some instructions to setup react-native environment in my devices using bellow steps are mentioned:

1. Homebrew install(***Version: 3.6.7*** ): `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
2. watchman install(***Version: 2022.10.24.00***): `brew install watchman`
3. Install Ruby(***version: 2.6.8p205***): `brew install ruby`
4. Install CocoaPods(***gem version: 3.0.3.1***): `sudo gem install cocoapods`
5. CocoaPods in fixed location(***pod version: 1.11.3***): `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin ffi cocoapods`

After successfully installed all of the aboves I was going to create react-native app using `npx react-native init AwesomeProject` comand and faced `Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5` error is also given in attached file. please check it and help me to suggest the way to solved.

[image: uby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5]

All of the resourses are mentioned below which I have follwed to solved this issues but i didn't solve it.

1. [How to fix "Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.5" while server starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914702/how-to-fix-your-ruby-version-is-2-3-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-2-5-while)
2. [Your Ruby version is 2.5.1 but your Gemfile specified 2.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52055992/your-ruby-version-is-2-5-1-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-4-0)
3. [rbenv Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094643/rbenv-your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-2)

Comment: Well Step 3 is your problem. You clearly installed 2.6.8 but your gemfile requires 2.7.5. So install 2.7.5 or change the Gemfile.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Below are the instructions which I have followed to solve this issue:

1. Homebrew install: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
2. watchman install: `brew install watchman`
3. Install Ruby: followed [rbenv Official Github Repo](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) link to install the required version of ruby
4. Install CocoaPods: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
5. CocoaPods in fixed location: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin ffi cocoapods`

After the environment setup, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 97):

You need to install the correct Ruby version. And it would be best if you use some ruby version manager for that. For example [rbenv](https://devhints.io/rbenv).

You can try these commands to install and change global Ruby version to 2.7.5

```
$ brew update
$ brew install ruby-build
$ brew install rbenv

$ rbenv install 2.7.5
$ rbenv global 2.7.5
```

After that, you need to export some configurations to define rbenv as default global ruby. For zsh users:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

And restart the terminal or run `source ~/.zshrc`.

For bash users just replace `zshrc` with `bashrc` in the above.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alexander, I tried it but I have faced another issues like Homebrew dosen't configured based on Gemfile. It's true that some of user can solved it to follows the aboves comands.

Comment: Can you describe that issue? What command do you run and what is the output with the error?

Comment: FYI: Rebooting the terminal was also required after running these commands.

Comment: Yes, a reboot is needed. Or you can run `source ~/.zshrc`.
That is assuming you are using zsh. 
Or you can replace it with `.bashrc` if using bash.

Comment: Update: In Macbook Ventura, this path has changed to `"$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"`

Comment: After follwoing the steps, you should either reboot your device or run source ~/.zshrc to get it working

Answer (score 13):

check version of your ruby first

```
ruby -v
```

if isn't 2.7.5 you must roll your version to 2.7.5

```
rvm install "ruby-2.7.5"
rvm use ruby-2.7.5 --default
```

Comment: Those who have a different version installed should make it default. For instance `rvm use ruby-2.7.5 --default`

Answer (score 2):

As Alexander says use `rbenv` or `rvm` to manage your ruby version. MacOS automatically brings a native version of ruby. You should avoid to update or change your native (MacOS) ruby version.

Further information why not to use system ruby and what are common issues: https://mac.install.guide/faq/do-not-use-mac-system-ruby/index.html

Comment: I Already tried by the version manager as rbenv and it solved and then I faced another issues that Homebrew dosen't match.

Comment: I experienced issues on ruby versions somehow they conflicts to each other

Answer (score 2):

Welp, actually no answer solved my issue.
This happens even if your ruby version is correct when you run "npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject".
But I found the solution.
When you see this error, you will still see the project folder created.
Go to the ios folder and run

```
bundle install && bundle exec pod install
```

problem solved.

Comment: Me too, the message is keep showing when running `npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject`. Are you saying that after doing bundle install you mention above, everything is ready to use? Does the project have complete files?

Comment: @JeafGilbert Yeah sure. I tested it by running ios app and it works perfectly.

Comment: Any idea to get rid of `bundle install` and do only the `pod install`?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution for me:

1. Clear **~/Library/Caches** folder
2. Make sure you are using the latest required by react-native ruby version

> ```
> ruby -v
> ```

3. Reboot terminal and try again

Answer (score 1):

This works ok! rvm use ruby-2.7.5 --default

Answer (score 1):

Run this command inside the directory where you want to create the new app, to check the list of available ruby versions:

`$ rvm list`

if you get this message:  `# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.`

Then run:

`$ rvm install 2.7.5` to install this specific version of ruby.

After installation is successful, run this command to make it default: `$ rvm use ruby-2.7.5 --default`

run again: `$ rvm list` to make sure that `ruby-2.7.5` is selected as default

if you see something like this:

```
 =*ruby-2.7.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.7.6 [ x86_64 ](other available version)
   ruby-3.0.0 [ x86_64 ](other available version)

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

then you are good to go, you can safely run your command:

`npx react-native init AwesomeProject`

and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to find a fix to update the ruby version for a local project after going through the above solutions, I found one on [ruby documentions](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#:%7E:text=GEM_HOME%20sets%20the%20default%20repository,to%20be%20searched%20for%20gems.). The [rbenv documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) was also helpful to understand the issue.

> RubyGems’ default local repository can be overridden with the GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME environment variables. GEM_HOME sets the default repository to install into. GEM_PATH allows multiple local repositories to be searched for gems.

Update the latest installed ruby version as default by copying the `rbenv` installed directory location found using `gem env home` and then past it in the `~/.zshrc` file under `export GEM_HOME=<directory-path>`.

After this, if you check the ruby version inside your project you will get the latest global version set by you from `rbenv`, eg:- `rbenv global 3.2.2`.

Once the version is set in your local project you can install the bundler and update the `cocoapods`.

Answer (score 0):

Can also use `asdf` to install it with `asdf install ruby 2.7.5` (or whatever version is needed)

Then switch using `asdf global ruby 2.7.5` and re-run your command.

See https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html to get started with `asdf`

Answer (score 0):

For me, i just went to my react native project folder, and open the GemFile, update the ruby version as the error msg suggests, then the error gone, Good luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35873

The guy who had the same problem with me, just fixed issue (including me)
right after deleting `/usr/local/bin/bundle`

Try this one after following all above instuctions and still getting issue

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the Gemfile type nano Gemfile on terminal window to open Gemfile
it should look like this

[image]

and just change ruby'2.7.5' version to which ruby version you want to specify your gemfile and control+X to save it you can specify your gemfile with any ruby version you need for the react native project 2.7.6 version is required for now

Answer (score 0):

In my own case since the project folder is created, i went to the ios folder

```
cd ios
```

and i open gem file and added this:

```
gem 'activesupport', '~> 6.1.5'
```

and then `bundle install` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

Operating system - macOS Monterey

version - 12.5.1

chip - Apple M2

steps to reproduce

1. npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject

error: your ruby-version is 2.6.8, but your gemfile specified is 2.6.10

https://mac.install.guide/ruby/13.html