# React native installation error in dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-native, macos, rubygems, bundler

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/395Tq.png)For mac os

Your RubyGems version (3.0.3.1) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundle

Your RubyGems version (3.0.3.1) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundle

Comment: Have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/74357983/20860690?

Answer (score 2):

*I struggled with this issue for 3 days and fix it*

**This steps work for me perfectly to create react native project without error**

1- npx react-native init testproject --skip-install -—npm

2- cd testproject

3- npm install or yearn install

4- cd ios

5- bundle config --local build.ffi --with-cflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration

6- bundle install

7- bundle exec pod install

**For more information about it [please check this link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11641#issuecomment-1540565288)**

**For More information about versions and complete error [please check this link too](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/37301#issuecomment-1540484759)**

> all my mac inforamtion and errors images are in shared links

Answer (score 1):

try to install ruby 2.7.6

```
rvm install "ruby-2.7.6"
```

or `bundle install` from the root of your project

Comment: tried both , not working

Comment: Same problem here as well