# Problems setting up mac m1 for reactNative when installing bundler

Tags: react-native, bundler

Trying to install dependencies for reactNative on mac air m1 but keep getting the same error.

I have installed homebrew, git, node, npm, watchman, ruby, gem, cocoapods.
When I initialize a appliction (npx react-native init project) I get the following message:
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing Bundler
error Your Ruby version is 3.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6

✖ Installing Bundler
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set.

Comment: "✖ Installing Bundler error Your Ruby version is 3.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6" is this not the problem?

Comment: Have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/74357983/20860690

Comment: Thank you Yakup Malikov for your successful solution,