# local ruby version not registering in gemfile

Tags: ruby, rbenv

The Ruby project that I'm trying to run specifies a requirement for Ruby version 2.1.2 in the Gemfile. Accordingly, I installed that version using rbenv and set it as the version for that repo using rbenv's `local` command. However, even after powering off my computer and restarting (not to mention running `rbenv rehash`), I still can't start the project, however rbenv confirms that I'm running 2.1.2 in that directory

```
bundle exec foreman start
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
travis-web > rbenv version
2.1.2 (set by /Users/me/sites/travis-web/.ruby-version)
```

Do you know how I can get the gemfile to read/acknowledge the local version (2.1.2)?

Comment: Do you have it installed? Just because it's in your version file doesn't mean it exists on your system. Ruby --version confirms what's running.

Comment: @DaveNewton it's listed when I run `rbenv install -l` and when I try to install it again, it says it already exists

Comment: What do you get when you run `ruby --version`?

Comment: @dpassage when I run `ruby --version` in that repo, I get `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin14.0]` when I run `ruby --version` in a different repo (i.e. any other repo), I get `ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]`.  Reminder, I set the local version for that repo (the problem repo) to be 2.1.2, so the results of `ruby --version` are what I'd expect

Comment: @JesseSielaff `which bundle` gives `/usr/bin/bundle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching versions might have dropped your bundler. The previous version had it, the new one doesn't. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061598/mavericks-rbenv-your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-1) for another related case.

Within that repo:

- `gem install bundler`
- `rbenv rehash`

[rbenv-bundler](https://github.com/carsomyr/rbenv-bundler) is a handy library that can do this for you upon each `bundle install`

Comment: Your answer solved the issue, but I have to wait 8 hours to award the bounty. Will come back. Thanks.