# "Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3-p194"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, gemfile

RVM won't let me run `bundle` because it thinks my Ruby version is different from what my Gemfile says, but it isn't:

```bsh
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p429 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.0.0-p195 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]
```

Gemfile:

```
ruby '1.9.3-p194'
```

But then:

```
$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3-p194
$
```

This seems like a very strange thing. Any ideas? There are a lot of people who have this question, but their Gemfiles are obviously different from the running version. I've even done `rvm use 1.9.3-p194` and then immediately after `bundle install` but I get the same error. `bundle update` produces the same error.

If I remove the ruby version from the Gemfile, it will default to 2.0.0 but switching by `rvm use` to the proper version (to comply with remote server ruby version) actually works. Running `bundle install` then *works*.

Could this error come from also having an rvmrc file (even though specifies the same ruby version) in the Rails project as well?

Comment: what about a bundle update?

Comment: `bundle update` runs into the same problem.

Comment: well then I would try an rvm update: `rvm get stable` or may be even updating bundle. Also, what happens if you don't specify ruby version in your Gemfile? and just keep the one selected by rvm.

Comment: If I remove it it defaults to 2.0.0. But if I then manually switch to 1.9.3-p194, and `bundle`, it runs.

Comment: sometimes using `rvm reload && cd .` has helped fix problems like this for me.

Comment: @Cyrus tried that, no luck...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The ruby directive explicitly leaves out the ability to specify a
>   patch level. Ruby patches often include important bug and security
>   fixes and are extremely compatible. 
>   http://bundler.io/v1.2/gemfile_ruby.html

The entry in your Gemfile should simply be `ruby '1.9.3'`

Comment: Works for me! Well, I mean, it doesn't work - it tries to load a more recent patch level, and failing that, loads 2.0.0. But this tells me why *that* doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Remove the line and add a file named '.ruby-version' with '1.9.3-p194' in it.  The .ruby-version approach is compatible with several ruby managers beyond rvm.

Comment: Valid point, but not a solution to the problem: I am not using other ruby managers.

Comment: But @BenSaufley other collaborators may be, and that is a point of using something that is supposed by several ruby managers, perhaps.

Comment: Nah, it's all good.  Sometimes it is hard to figure out what is indicated or meant.  Deleting prior comments to keep this area clean. :)