# Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

When I run

```
rails server
```

I get the error.

There is some problem loading the gemsets

```
$rvm list
rvm rubies
ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ i686 ]
ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ i686 ]
=* ruby-2.1.0 [ i686 ]
# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

$ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]

$rails -v
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0

$bundle show rails
/home/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rails-4.0.1

$bundle exec rails s
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0

bundle exec ruby -v
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]
```

I did `bundle install` and tried to start the rails server but it gave the same error.

### bashrc

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.0'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '2.3.1'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'haml', '4.0.4'
gem 'actionpack-page_caching', '1.0.2' #use caches_pages in rails 4
gem 'twitter'
gem 'mina'
group :production do
  gem 'dalli', '2.6.4'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end
group :test do
  gem 'watir-rails'
end
group :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

**UPDATE**

I tried restarting my computer, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: show output of: `bundle show rails`

Comment: what happens with `bundle exec ruby -v`? Try logging out of the console and opening a new session too..

Comment: try `rvm use 2.1.0@your_gemset --default`

Comment: You've not installed Ruby 2.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is your `PATH` environment variable, it has to match `GEM_PATH` and in your case it does not. To fix it run:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

This will update your shell initialization files and make sure rvm is properly loaded. Then open a new terminal (close the application and open it again), and run:

```
rvm use 2.1.0
```

On both steps read all the messages printed to you. They are important and contain information about how to fix your problems. RVM detects problems and tries to fix them or warns you about them if they can not or should not be fixed automatically.

Comment: it was working fine before i did something 'rvm clean' and then updated rvm. i wanted to install a new ruby version. anyway, i was in a hurry so i uninstalled rvm and made a clean installation.

Comment: did you follow the steps I listed?

Comment: unfortunately, i reinstalled rvm before your answer was posted. but before that, i did try to get the list of stable ruby versions using  'rvm get stable' without '--auto-dotfiles' which might have broken something.

Comment: no `rvm get stable` can not break anything, but if you call it with `--auto-dotfiles` it can fix your shell initialization files loading of rvm, it's still important you read all the messages rvm prints as they point out things that can or should not be fixed automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, and used @mpapis advises, fixing my `$PATH` and rvm loading.

But I had to run `gem install bundler` to update bundler and make it recognize my current ruby version again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a `.ruby-version` file in the top-level directory of your project. That file would contain the ruby version spec'd in your `Gemfile`, e.g.

```
2.1.0
```

That apparently is the cross-`{rbenv,rvm}` way of spec'ing the version now.