# Not able to install gem in 1.9 folder after upgrading from 1.8 to 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9

i'm trying to upgrade my server from ruby 1.8 to 1.9 and i did that with following link. 
[http://kb.site5.com/ruby-on-rails/select-a-version-of-ruby-for-your-hosting-account/]

i did all the things, Now 
ruby -v : ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

but when i run bundle install it installs it in /vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8 folder.
but when i try to run the code it checks in /vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1 folder.

i can't seem to run my site. i specified ruby "1.9.3" in gem filoe and try to tun bundle install it gives me an error "**your ruby version is 1.8.7 but your gemfile specified 1.9.3**"

which ruby : /user/local/ruby19/bin

### i changed gemrc cat .gemrc

gempath: [/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1,
      /home/XXX/ruby/gems] also.

my site says bundle install error [image]

After that i tried to copy all the gems from 1.8 folder to 1.9 in vender because it was looking there  then i got this error because nokogir was insalled for 1.8 and needed higher version.

[image]

Any idea?? i have been stuck here from hours!!!

Comment: Can you check your .rvmrc file. possible that ruby 1.8 specified there

Comment: Did you do all that changes run under the same user account as the user account your webserver uses?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995271/rails-server-error-ruby-version-is-1-8-7-but-your-gemfile-specified-1-9-3/21557162#21557162

Comment: please provide `which bundler`, and `cat $(which bundler)|head -n 1` from the project's folder

Comment: Please post your gemfile as well as VHost configuration? Are you using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: rvm use 1.9.3  -bash : rvm: command not found 

<br/>

which bundler => /home/swapclon/.gems/bin/bundler  <br/>
cat $(which bundler)|head -n 1  => #!/user/bin/ruby

Comment: /home/swapclon/.gemrc   file content (This might Help)                                                          
---
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
gemhome: /home/swapclon/.gems
gempath:  
- /home/swapclon/.gems  
- /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8  
:benchmark: false  
:update_sources: true  
:verbose: false  
:backtrace: false  
:sources:  
- http://gems.rubyforge.org/  
- http://rubygems.org/  
:bulk_threshold: 1000

Comment: @Akki209 just replace in `/home/swapclon/.gems/bin/bundler` the head to `#!/user/bin/env ruby`, then issue `bundle install`

Comment: Couple of questions if you don't mind. 
1) How can i do that, change what to  i can code ruby but lack knowledge of config and ENV stuff?
2) now i just updated the ruby version to 1.8.7 to 1.9 i was using multiple rails site with 1.8.7 on this server, Do i have to bundle install on all of the? or dose that have backward compatibility.   
  

Thanks for all the help guys,appreciated !!

Comment: @Akki209 1) I don't undorstan you here, please explain in the post. 2)  you shell do `bundle install` each time you have change you configuation, for example change the ruby version.

Comment: just replace in /home/swapclon/.gems/bin/bundler the head to #!/user/bin/env ruby, then issue bundle install ***** I don't know how to change that.

Comment: @Akki209 open the file `/home/swapclon/.gems/bin/bundler` to edit, with any of the text file editors, and then just fix the first line.

Comment: Hey sorry for late replay, That worked,Thanks a ton.
i'll mark it right once you answer it.